# How to deal with multiple p tags inside td tags with pandas.read_html?

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, python-3.9

I am using `pandas.read_html()` to get tables from a html page. In one of the tables, one of the `<td>` tags has multiple `<p>` tags inside it. And read_html ignores `<p>` just outputs text without any whitespace characters.

I want some way to split the text and parse later. Is there an option I can pass to `read_html` to add some kind of whitespace or special character between `<p>` tags?

Comment: what's the url. I think you're going to have to use beautifulsoup here. Don't think `pandas` implementation of bs4 will account for tags within `<td>` tags.

Comment: I suppose you could still use pandas, but would have to use beautifulsoup prior to have pandas read it in to deal/remove the `<p>` tags, but leave the content

Comment: @chitown88 it's a confluence page for the organization and has all confidential stuff, so I can't share the snippet of the html from the url. Can you give some hint about how to use use bs4 to deal with the ```<p>``` prior to pandas? or any bs4 way to deal with tables?

Comment: If it has confidential stuff, you can atleast share the structure of the ```<table>``` with some dummy data in it. Right ?