# How do I split cells in Pandas dataframe that have combined data from HTML tables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas combining multiple cells into one cell? Website or function problem?

```
import pandas as pd

tables=pd.read_html('http://www.ufcstats.com/fight-details/451525a1abe30a91')
```

This says there are four tables. But in those tables, the actual data is being combined. For example 39 of 102  26 of 73 should be 2 cells. But its 1?

I tried to extract the tables individually and then split them

```
df=tables[0].values.tolist()

print(type(df[0][0]))

print(re.split("\s{2,}",df[0][0]))
```

This achieves nothing. It just bounces back the cell with no change. Unsure of what is wrong, not even an error.

Is there a way to iterate over the entire dataframe and split where there is double spaces present? without changing its structure.

Comment: You have the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096283/how-to-deal-with-multiple-p-tags-inside-td-tags-with-pandas-read-html), although this also has no answer.  I would suggest using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` together to retrieve the individuals rows (which will require a lot more code than the above), because you will need to split each "cell" up for the different paragraphs within - if you inspect the tables you will find in each `td` there are two `<p> ... <\p>` sections.

Comment: Your code above is not splitting because you are using `"\s{2,}"` which means 2 or more blank spaces.  If you change this to `"\s{1,}"` then it will look for `>=1` spaces in a row to split on.  However, you will find that this also splits the text on the rows that you want to keep.  If you inspect the strings, there are not actually any double spaces, which is why it was not working.

Comment: you can try to make extra function that check the double spaces and apply it to your data in html format. Something like that:
# Define a custom function to split cells with double spaces
def split_cells(cell):
    if isinstance(cell, str):
        return re.split('\s{2,}', cell)
    return cell

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if pandas can parse nested data/paragraphs inside each `<td>` tag.

But anyways, (*as a good start*) here is one way to parse the first table with [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) :

```
#pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html5lib")

table = soup.find("table")

headers = [col.text.strip() for col in table.find("thead").find_all("th")]

data = [
    [p.text.strip() for p in cell.find_all("p")]
    for row in table.find_all("tr") for cell in row.find_all("td")
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.set_axis(headers, axis=1)
```

Ouptut :

| Fighter | KD | Sig. str. | Sig. str. % | Total str. | Td | Td % | Sub. att | Rev. | Ctrl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jessica Andrade | 0 | 131 of 322 | 40% | 148 of 342 | 2 of 3 | 66% | 0 | 0 | 1:35 |
| Angela Hill | 1 | 89 of 209 | 42% | 99 of 220 | 0 of 0 | --- | 0 | 0 | 0:06 |

With [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), we get :

| Fighter | KD | Sig. str. | Sig. str. % | Total str. | Td | Td % | Sub. att | Rev. | Ctrl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jessica Andrade Angela Hill | 0 1 | 131 of 322 89 of 209 | 40% 42% | 148 of 342 99 of 220 | 2 of 3 0 of 0 | 66% --- | 0 0 | 0 0 | 1:35 0:06 |